# Directly including Reference for CV inplace, however, each line shifting right

Tags: formatting, cv, resume

I am really struggling to put together a CV which can use a `.bib` file and I can directly enter inline reference, without citing somewhere in the document.

I used one of the examples from this site stackexchange to include references directly in place for a CV. The toy example worked fine, however, when using it with my `.cls` file, the publications section seems to be shifted to the right-side of the paper a little bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have put together a minimal working example to demonstrate this.

Overleaf MWE link:
[Overleaf Link](https://www.overleaf.com/6653763641pzjmpfswdqmb)

Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Edit:
I am also attaching the code for the MWE:

`res.cls` file

```
\typeout{Document Style `res' <26 Sep 89>.}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{res}[2000/05/19 v1.4b Resume class]

\PassOptionsToClass{11pt,12pt}{article}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

\newif\if@line
\newif\if@margin

\DeclareOption{line}{\@linetrue}
\DeclareOption{centered}{\@linefalse}

\DeclareOption{margin}{\@margintrue}
\DeclareOption{overlapped}{\@marginfalse}

\ExecuteOptions{overlapped,centered}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\nofiles         %



\newtoks\tabular@text           % holds the current list being processed
\newtoks\tabular@head           % holds the head tabular list
\newtoks\tabular@tail           % holds the tail tabular list
\newtoks\@ta                % used by \@append
\newtoks\undefined@token\undefined@token={}

    
\typeout{Document Style `res' <26 Sep 89>.}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{res}[2000/05/19 v1.4b Resume class]

\PassOptionsToClass{11pt,12pt}{article}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

\newif\if@line
\newif\if@margin

\DeclareOption{line}{\@linetrue}
\DeclareOption{centered}{\@linefalse}

\DeclareOption{margin}{\@margintrue}
\DeclareOption{overlapped}{\@marginfalse}

\ExecuteOptions{overlapped,centered}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\nofiles         % resume's don't need .aux files


\newtoks\tabular@text           % holds the current list being processed
\newtoks\tabular@head           % holds the head tabular list
\newtoks\tabular@tail           % holds the tail tabular list
\newtoks\@ta                % used by \@append
\newtoks\undefined@token\undefined@token={}


\def\@printcentername{\begingroup
  % print the name centered
  \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth{\hfil\@tablebox{\namefont\@name}\hfil}\par
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{%
    % do nothing
  }{%
    \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
      % only one address
      \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth{\hfil\@tablebox{\@addressone}\hfil}\par
    }{
      % two addresses
      \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth{\@tablebox{\@addressone}\hfil
                     \@tablebox{\@addresstwo}}\par
    }%
  }%
\endgroup}

\def\namefont{\large\bf}
\def\@linename{\begingroup
  \def\\{, }
  {\namefont\@name}
  \vskip 2pt
  \fullline
  \vskip 2pt
  % where do you live?
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{%
    % do nothing
  }{%
    \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth
      {\hfill\vbox{\hbox{\@addressone}
           \hbox{\@addresstwo}
          }%
      }\par
  }
\endgroup}

\let\print@name\relax
\def\ds@centered{\ifx\print@name\relax\let\print@name\@printcentername\fi}
\def\ds@line{\ifx\print@name\relax\let\print@name\@linename\fi}

\def\sectionfont{\bf}
\newdimen\sectionwidth
\newskip\sectionskip
\newdimen\resumewidth

\resumewidth=6.5in
\sectionskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus -.2ex % values stolen from LaTeX

\def\newsectionwidth#1{%
             \sectionwidth=#1
             \textwidth=\resumewidth
             \advance\textwidth-\sectionwidth
             \hsize=\textwidth
             \hoffset=\sectionwidth
}


\def\boxed@sectiontitle#1{%

  % ...
  \ifx\\\@tabcr    % is this in a tabular? (this *should* work but is a cludge)
    \@stopfield    % the is the first part of a \kill
   \else
     \@@par      % This will end the previous paragraph if needed and
           % go into vertical mode.  If this was already in
           % vertical mode then the \par does nothing.

  \fi
  \begingroup
  \everypar={}%
  \def\par{\@@par}%
  \let\\=\@normalcr
  \addpenalty{\@secpenalty} % this would be a good place for a page break
                % \@secpenalty is what LaTeX uses before its
                % section's.  It happens to be -300
  \addvspace{\sectionskip}  % put in a bit of glue

  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \hss     % this is an llap.  In other words, this glue
         % will shrink by the width of the stuff in the vbox
         % (\sectionwidth) into the left margin and then
         % insert the contents of the vbox.
    \vtop to 0pt{% make a 0pt height paragraph, with the baseline at the
         % lined up with the baseline of the first box in the list
      \leftskip=0pt
      \hsize=\sectionwidth
      \textwidth=\sectionwidth
      \raggedright     % you don't want this filled out to the right margin
      \sectionfont
      #1\vss           % Go into horizontal mode; do the paragraph;
               % go into vertical mode; add some negative glue 
               % to give a box of 0pt height and depth
    }%
  }%
  \addpenalty{-\@secpenalty} % this would be a bad place for a page break
  \vskip-\baselineskip % when the next box is processed, baselineskip glue

  \endgroup
  \ifx\\\@tabcr   
    \@startline
    \ignorespaces
  \else
    \vskip-\parskip    
  \fi
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This is for sectiontitles that are entirely above the section text
%
\def\unboxed@sectiontitle#1{%
  \ifx\\\@tabcr % see boxed@sectiontitle for explation
    \@stopfield
   \else
     \@@par
  \fi
  \begingroup
  \everypar={}%
  \def\par{\@@par}%
  \def\\{ }
  \addpenalty{\@secpenalty}
  \addvspace{\sectionskip}
  \hbox to 0pt{\hss\hbox to \sectionwidth{\sectionfont#1\hss}}
  \addpenalty{-\@secpenalty} % this would be a bad place for a page break
  \endgroup
  \ifx\\\@tabcr   % see boxed@sectiontitle for explation
    \@startline
  \else
    \vskip-\parskip
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
}

\let\@@section\relax
\def\ds@overlapped{\ifx\@@section\relax\newsectionwidth{0.5in}\let
  \@@section\unboxed@sectiontitle\fi}
\def\ds@margin{\ifx\@@section\relax\newsectionwidth{1.3in}\let
  \@@section\boxed@sectiontitle\fi}

%\input article.sty

\if@line\ds@line\else\ds@centered\fi
\if@margin\ds@margin\else\ds@overlapped\fi


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% typeset resume all nice and pretty
%
\def\Resume{{R\'{e}sum\'{e}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% makes a line of width \textwidth starting at -\hoffset
%
\def\fullline{      % hrules only listen to \hoffset
  \nointerlineskip  % so I have this code     
  \moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\textwidth} 
  \nointerlineskip
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% create a multiline box.
%
\def\@tablebox#1{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}#1\end{tabular}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% use this to define your name
%
\def\name#1{\def\@name{#1}}

\def\@name{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% use this to define your address, this may be called more than once.
%
\let\@addressone\relax
\let\@addresstwo\relax

\def\address#1{
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{\def\@addressone{#1}}{\def\@addresstwo{#1}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\opening{\def\@opening{}
  \begingroup
  \leftskip=-\hoffset        % I use leftskip to move things to the left as 
  \advance\textwidth\hoffset % changing hoffset doesn't work. But this
  \hsize=\textwidth      % doesn't really work as hboxes are rules
                 % are unaffeted
  \let\par=\@@par
  \parindent=0pt
  \parskip=0pt
  \print@name
  \endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% all of the resume goes in the resume environment
%
\newenvironment{resume}{\begingroup
               \@ifundefined{@opening}{\opening}{}
}{\endgroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\def\@endpbox{\par\egroup\hfil}
\let\@@endpbox=\@endpbox

\newdimen\@columnwidth    % the width of each column equal to
\def\ncolumn#1{%
  % \@columnwidth = \textwidth / #1
  \@columnwidth=\textwidth \divide\@columnwidth by #1
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]%
    {*{#1}{@{}p{\@columnwidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}}
}

\def\endncolumn{\end{tabular*}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\employer#1{\def\@employer{\print@employer{#1}}}
\def\location#1{\def\@location{\print@location{#1}}}
\def\dates#1{\def\@dates{\print@dates{#1}}}
\def\title#1{\def\@title{\print@title{#1}}}

\let\l@justify\raggedright
\let\r@justify\raggedleft
\let\c@justify\centering


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\@format#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname print@#1\endcsname##1{%
    {\csname#2@justify\endcsname##1\par}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcounter{numberofcolumns}
\newenvironment{format}{%
  \def\end@line@head{\append@tabular@head{tabular@text}\tabular@text={}%
    \c@numberofcolumns 0}
  \def\end@line@tail{\append@tabular@tail{tabular@text}\tabular@text={}%
    \c@numberofcolumns 0}
  \tabular@text={}
  \tabular@head={}
  \tabular@tail={}
  \c@numberofcolumns 0
  \let\\=\end@line@head
  \def\employer##1{\advance\c@numberofcolumns 1
           \@format{employer}{##1}
           \append@tabular@text{employer}}
  \def\location##1{\advance\c@numberofcolumns 1
           \@format{location}{##1}
           \append@tabular@text{location}}
  \def\dates##1{\advance\c@numberofcolumns 1
        \@format{dates}{##1}
        \append@tabular@text{dates}}
  \def\title##1{\advance\c@numberofcolumns 1
         \@format{title}{##1}
        \append@tabular@text{title}}
  \def\body{\iftoks\tabular@head\undefined@token\then
        \else
          \@append{\noexpand\\}\to\tabular@head
        \skotfi
        \let\\=\end@line@tail}}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%taken from page 378 of TeXbook but freely hacked
%
% appends the expansion of #1 to the token list #2

\def\@append#1\to#2{%
  \@ta=\expandafter{#1}%
  \xdef\@append@temp{\the#2\the\@ta}
  \global#2=\expandafter{\@append@temp}%
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CHAA006%vaxb.rhbnc.ac.uk@NSS.Cs.Ucl.AC.UK
% texhax.88.078
% is used to see if two token lists are equal
% there must be a better way
%

\let \then = \empty
\def \iftoks #1#2\then #3\else #4\skotfi{
        \edef \1{\the #1}
        \edef \2{\the #2}
        \ifx \1\2\then #3\else #4\fi}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\def\append@tabular@text#1{%
\iftoks\tabular@text\undefined@token\then
  \global\tabular@text=\expandafter{\csname @#1\endcsname}
\else
  \@append{&}\to\tabular@text
  \@append{\csname @#1\endcsname}\to\tabular@text
\skotfi
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%
\def\append@tabular@head#1{%
  \ifnum\the\c@numberofcolumns=0\relax
  \else
    \iftoks\tabular@head\undefined@token\then
      \relax
    \else
      \@append{\noexpand\\}\to\tabular@head
      \@append{\noexpand\penalty-\@secpenalty}\to\tabular@head
    \skotfi
    \@append{\noexpand\begin{ncolumn}}\to\tabular@head
    \@append{\expandafter{\the\c@numberofcolumns}}\to\tabular@head
    \@append{\the\csname#1\endcsname}\to\tabular@head
    \@append{\noexpand\end{ncolumn}}\to\tabular@head
  \fi
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%
\def\append@tabular@tail#1{%
  \ifnum\the\c@numberofcolumns=0\relax
  \else
    \iftoks\tabular@tail\undefined@token\then
    \else
      \@append{\noexpand\\}\to\tabular@tail
      \@append{\noexpand\penalty-\@secpenalty}\to\tabular@tail
    \skotfi
    \@append{\noexpand\begin{ncolumn}}\to\tabular@tail
    \@append{\expandafter{\the\c@numberofcolumns}}\to\tabular@tail
    \@append{\the\csname#1\endcsname}\to\tabular@tail
    \@append{\noexpand\end{ncolumn}}\to\tabular@tail
  \fi
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{position}%
  {%
   \begingroup
     \par
       \the\tabular@head
%     \addpenalty{-\@secpenalty}% bad place for a page break
     \penalty -\@secpenalty % bad place for a page break
     \penalty 10000
     \ignorespaces
  }{%
       \the\tabular@tail
%     \addpenalty{\@secpenalty}% good place for a page break
     \penalty \@secpenalty % good place for a page break
    \endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\@secpenalty = -500
\topmargin 0pt
\headheight 0pt
\headsep 0pt
\textheight 9in
\parindent 0pt
\topmargin 0in
\oddsidemargin 0pt
\evensidemargin 0pt
\marginparwidth 0pt
\parindent 0pt
\parskip \baselineskip
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\def\@listI{\leftmargin\leftmargini
\topsep 0pt 
\parskip 0pt
\partopsep 2pt plus 2pt
\parsep 2pt plus 2pt
\itemsep \parsep}

\pagestyle{empty}  % don't want page numbers

\begin{format}
\title{l}\employer{r}\\
\location{l}\dates{r}\\
\body\\
\end{format}

\let\section\@@section
```

Code for `main.tex` file:

```
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{res}

% use your favourite citation style here
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother


% hanging publications: 1st line starts at beginning of line, 
% further lines are placed a bit to the right
% \usepackage{hanging}
% \newcommand\publication[1]{%
%   \smallskip\par\hangpara{1.5em}{1}\bibentry{#1}\smallskip
% }

\usepackage{hanging}
\newcommand\publication[1]{%
    \smallskip\par\hangpara{1.5em}{1}\bibentry{#1}\smallskip
}


\begin{document}
    
    % bibliography
    \nobibliography{publications.bib}
    \bibliographystyle{apacite} 

    \section{Publications}  
    
    % optional: split into different subsections for
    % peer-reviewed articles, conference abstracts, ...

    % example with links
    \publication{Geirhos2017}
        (\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06969}{link}, \href{https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.06969.pdf}{pdf}, \href{https://github.com/rgeirhos/object-recognition}{data and materials})
    
    % example without links
    \publication{Knuth1998}
    
    % the cumbersome way
%   \hangpara{1.5em}{1}Knuth, D. E. (1998). 
%   \textit{The art of computer programming: sorting and searching} (Vol. 3). Pearson Education.
    
\end{document}
```

And a toy `publications.bib` file:

```
@article{Geirhos2017,
  title={Comparing deep neural networks against humans: object recognition when the signal gets weaker},
  author={Geirhos, Robert and Janssen, David HJ and Sch{\"u}tt, Heiko H and Rauber, Jonas and Bethge, Matthias and Wichmann, Felix A},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1706.06969},
  year={2017}}

@book{Knuth1998,
  title={The art of computer programming: sorting and searching},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin},
  volume={3},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Pearson Education}}
```

Comment: Please do not post links to your document, but put the code of your MWE into the question itself. At the moment accessing the document requires an Overleaf login and your code will be lost once the link expires.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question to add the code. :)